# How to add two int array values together?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to add two int arrays together to get a sum. The first array contains 0000000000000000123456789 and the second array contains 0001111111111111111111111. The sum should be 1111111111111234567900. Also I'm trying to do this without BigInteger or BigDecimal.

```
for(int i=0; i<number1.length;i++){
   add= number1[i]+number2[i];
   if(plus>=10){    
       sum[i-1]+=add/10;
       sum[i] = add%10;
    }else{
        sum[i]=add;
    }                   
}
```

The output that is produced at the moment is 00011111111111112345678100.  How can I fix my code so that the 8 becomes a 9?

Comment: What is `plus`?

Comment: that is not how we represent an array....

Comment: How many elements are in `0000000000000000123456789`?

Comment: plus is an int, and there 25 elements total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kinda works. I can think of a couple of cases where something like this would break, like if the arrays were like {9,9,9} and {9,9,9}, `result` would be {9,9,8} instead of {1,9,9,8}. **It's a minor fix that is being left as an activity to the reader.**

```
public static void main(String []args){
    int[] number1 = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int[] number2 = {0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};

    int carry = 0, sum = 0;

    int[] result = new int[number1.length];
    for (int i = number1.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        sum = number1[i] + number2[i] + carry;
        result[i] = sum%10;
        carry = sum/10;
    }
    // [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 0, 0]                                                                   
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result)); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for properly carrying numbers greater than 10 to the next up and keep the lower numbers!

```
int[] result = new int[number1.length+1];
        for (int i=number1.length-1; i>=0;i--){
            result[i+1] = number1[i] + number[i] + result[i+1];
            if(result[i+1] >= 10){
                result[i+1] -= 10; // it could never be more than 20 so this is ok and if it is 10 than it will still carry over to the next
                result[i] = 1; // the ten carried to the next one
            }
        }
```

Similar to Seek Addo's answer, but avoids the errors found in his code that prevent the application from properly carrying the numbers.

This is the most compact way I could think to do it, and should yield the proper answers of

> [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,0,0] or 1111111111111234567900

Comment: `result[i] - 10;`?

Comment: `int[] result`. Can't check for null.

Comment: Please compile your code before submitting. [[web-based sandbox](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php)]. This piece of code has a lot of compilation errors.

Comment: You should try to compile and run your code. My previous comments show errors in your code

Comment: `for-loop` goes from `0 to number1.length-1`. len(result) = len(number1). The line `result[i+1]` will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: presently, the most-significant digit is ignored. `result[i] != 1`? There is no reason to have this.

Comment: It's kinda close. See what's going wrong. I have uploaded your code here.  [link](http://ideone.com/eEbWTY)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        int[] number = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        int[] number2 = {0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
        int[] result = new int[number.length+1];
        int carry = 0;
        for (int i = number.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            result[i+1] = number[i] + number2[i] + carry;
            if (result[i+1] > 9) {
                carry = result[i+1] - 9;
                result[i+1] -= 10;
            }
            else {
                carry = 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not good. This is my version of it (support for different array sizes):

```
public static int[] sumIntArrays(int[] n1, int[] n2) {
    int n1Size = n1.length - 1, n2Size = n2.length - 1, indexSum = n1Size > n2Size ? n1Size + 2 : n2Size + 2, slack = 0, s;
    int[] sum = new int[indexSum];
    while (true) {
        if (n1Size < 0 && n2Size < 0)
            break;
        s = (n1Size < 0 ? 0 : n1[n1Size--]) + (n2Size < 0 ? 0 : n2[n2Size--]) + slack;
        if (s > 9) {
            sum[--indexSum] = s % 10;
            slack = s / 10;
        } else {
            sum[--indexSum] = s;
            slack = 0;
        }
    }
    if (slack != 0)
        sum[0] = slack;
    return sum;
}
```